# Failed to open - Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework2

> Warning: require_once(Zend/Application.php) [function.require-once]:
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\obsessa\public\index.php on line 17
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening
>   required 'Zend/Application.php'
>   (include_path='D:\xampp\htdocs\obsessa\library;.;D:/xampp/php/PEAR;D:/xampp/php/ZendFramework')
>   in D:\xampp\htdocs\obsessa\public\index.php on line 17

Hi Anyone help me on this ?

Comment: please do paste zend folder in library folder of the project

Comment: Done !!! but still the same issue

Comment: Please set the path of the library in index.php file //Ensure library/ is on include_path set_include_path( implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'), get_include_path(),))); /** Zend_Application */ require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

Comment: Failed opening required 'Zend/Application.php' (include_path='D:\xampp\htdocs\obsessa\library')

code is
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    
)));

Comment: Pleas read the step 4 now I am not able to chat with you reason your repo is :6

Comment: Now working !!! Its my mistake !!! I downloaded framework 2.0 library !!! :)

Answer (score 0):

> D:/xampp/php/PEAR;D:/xampp/php/ZendFramework

Should probably be:

`D:/xampp/php/PEAR;D:/xampp/php/ZendFramework/library`

The immediate problem is that your php include_path configuration is wrong.  The reason is the way PSR-0 autoloading works.  Your include path has two paths.  If you want to load Zend\Application, then you need an include path that has a subdirectory called 'Zend'.  In your case, `D:/xampp/php/ZendFramework` does not have that, you need `D:/xampp/php/ZendFramework/library` (which has a subdirectory named `Zend`, which has a file named `Application.php`)

But really, if you're doing ZF2, grab the skeleton application and use composer, just like the docs say, especially if you're new.  composer is fantastic, and it's the preferred way to go.  With composer, each application you write has its own installation of zf2.  There are very few situations where you want your apps to rely on some globally-installed framework, which is the setup you're trying to do.

Comment: Dear friend, Thank you for your reply. I am new to zend framework!!!. I have to set one zend framework project in my local machine!!! I download the files and placed in htdocs folder.
Where to find Application.php ?
Can you help me on include_path ?

Answer (score 0):

## Please follow this step :

1. Please donwload the zend libray from zend official site 
   http://framework.zend.com/
2. Then paste donwloaded library in zend libray folder
3. Index.php file settings

   //Ensure library/ is on include_path
       set_include_path(
               implode(PATH_SEPARATOR,
                       array(realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
                               get_include_path(),)));
       /** Zend_Application */
       require_once 'Zend/Application.php';
4. please set index.php file as:

   // Define path to application directory
   defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
       || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(**FILE**) . '/../application'));

   defined('LIBRARY_PATH')
   || define('LIBRARY_PATH', realpath(dirname(**FILE**) . '/../library'));

   // Define application environment
   defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
       || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));
   define('PUBLIC_PATH','http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/demo/public');
   // Ensure library/ is on include_path
   set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
       realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
       get_include_path(),
   )));
   set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
   realpath(DOCTRINE_PATH),
   get_include_path(),
   )));
   /** Zend_Application */
   require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

   // Create application, bootstrap, and run
   $application = new Zend_Application(
       APPLICATION_ENV,
       APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
   );
   $application->bootstrap()
               ->run();

Comment: Where to paste the downloaded file ?

Comment: abc->library (abc project name )

Comment: i placed downloaded library folder within abc. Now how to change include_path ?

Comment: Where to find Application.php in Zend folder ?